# javascript count visible elements

Tags: javascript

I have been searching the forums but unable find any specific help in relation to my problem. I am trying to design an application using javascript which will count div elements which are either hidden or visible.

I am using

```
document.getElementById("div-element").childElementCount;
```

and could use something like:

```
document.querySelectorAll('#div-element .dic-class').length;
```

both of which work as intended by returning the total elements.

I am changing the visibility of specific div elements by:

```
document.getElementById('div-element').style.display == "block or none";
```

Comment: Would you like to use jquey to do this?

Comment: I have been looking but I have designed my whole application with Javascript and would like to see if I could complete it with just this I know I can do this with Jquery

Comment: "Visible" as in in the viewport, or in CSS not set to `display: none`/ `visibility: hidden`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For something like this `Array.prototype.filter` comes to mind (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), but you can't use that on a `nodelist`, which is what you get when using `querySelectorAll`, so I would solve this by converting the `nodelist` to an array, then use `filter` on that.

To convert a nodelist to an array:

```
var array = [].slice.call(someNodeList);
```

(https://davidwalsh.name/nodelist-array)

So, we can do this:

```
//gives node list
divs = document.querySelectorAll('#div-element > div');
//convert to an array
var divsArray = [].slice.call(divs);
//so now we can use filter
//find all divs with display none
var displayNone = divsArray.filter(function(el) {
    return getComputedStyle(el).display === "none"
});
//and all divs that are not display none
var displayShow = divsArray.filter(function(el) {
    return getComputedStyle(el).display !== "none"
});
//and use length to count
var numberOfHiddenDivs = displayNone.length;
var numberOfVisibleDivs = displayShow.length;
```

Just a note: its important to use `getComputedStyle` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) rather than `element.style` because `element.style` will not reflect properties applied by css, it will only reflect inline styles.

Second note, this only counts `"display:none;"` as hidden, if you also want to include `visibility:hidden;` or some other criteria, use

```
var displayNone = divsArray.filter(function(el) {
    return getComputedStyle(el).display === "none" ||
        getComputedStyle(el).visibility === "hidden"
});
//and all divs that are not display none
var displayShow = divsArray.filter(function(el) {
    return !(getComputedStyle(el).display === "none" ||
        getComputedStyle(el).visibility === "hidden")
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
//gives node list
divs = document.querySelectorAll('#div-element > div');
//convert to an array
var divsArray = [].slice.call(divs);
//so now we can use filter
//find all divs with display none
var displayNone = divsArray.filter(function(el) {
    return getComputedStyle(el).display === "none"
});
//and all divs that are not display none
var displayShow = divsArray.filter(function(el) {
    return getComputedStyle(el).display !== "none"
});
//and use length to count
var numberOfHiddenDivs = displayNone.length;
var numberOfVisibleDivs = displayShow.length;
alert("hidden:"+numberOfHiddenDivs+", visible:"+numberOfVisibleDivs);
```

```css
#div-element > div{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid gold;
    background-color:red;
}
div.hide{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id='div-element'>
    <div class=hide></div>
    <div class=hide></div>
    <div class=hide></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class=hide></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class=hide></div>
    <div></div>
    <div style=display:none;></div>
    <div style=display:none;></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You used jquey while @Stepnage want to do this in pure js

Comment: @Mohammad what? I didn't. please point out what you think is jquery.

Answer (score 5):

While you are changing the visibility of specific div elements by `document.getElementById('div-element').style.display = "none";` the count of visible and hidden elements can be easily performed by checking a "generated" style `display` attribute:

```
var countHidden = document.querySelectorAll("#div-element .dic-class[style='display: none;']").length;
var countVisible = document.querySelectorAll("#div-element .dic-class:not([style='display: none;'])").length;
```

Comment: I must admit that this solution works *surprisingly* well for me. It deserves more upvotes!

Answer (score 1):

Loop the items and then you can check the style by checking [**`offsetParent`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent) , then push to an array.

```js
var elem = document.querySelectorAll('#div-element .dic-class');
var visible = [];
for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
  _this = elem[i];
  if (_this.offsetParent !== null)
    visible.push(elem[i]);
}
alert(visible.length);
```

```css
#div-element {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-element">
  <div class="dic-class"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohh this looks promising I will give it a go, thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward and accurate way to accomplish what @Stepnage wanted to do (at least what I think he wanted to do).

Comment: Basically I have a desktop environment with icons, when each icon is hidden or visible a text value is updated with the remaining visible or hidden and the total element.

Comment: Thank you Rejith, this seams to be the most effective solution, I will integrate this into my code and see how it performs.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the NodeList into an array and then apply [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get the number of elements that don't have the display set to none inline:

```js
var divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#div-element .dic-class'));

console.log(divs.reduce(function(a, b){return a + (b.style.display != "none" ? 1 : 0)}, 0))
```

```css
.dic-class {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-element">
  <div class="dic-class"></div>
  <div class="dic-class"></div>
  <div class="dic-class" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="dic-class" style="display: none"></div>
  <div class="dic-class"></div>
</div>
```

If you want to check for applies rules (not just inline ones), you can use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) instead.

Comment: @Mohammad, it doesn't work with other stuff as well, but I'm answering the question: `I am changing the visibility of specific div elements by:

document.getElementById('div-element').style.display == "block or none";`. As I wrote, you can play with computed style to cover every case you need.

Comment: @Stepnage, did you see my solution or just ignoring it?

Comment: @Shomz sorry no I did not see it I am new here so getting their I am integrating three solutions but as a function call so I can change one value and see which solution works the best for my application, I will be interacting with the returned value at a later date.

Comment: Ah, so I thought you missed it because you were interacting with everyone else. :)  Yeah, it should be simple making it a function, I just wanted to should you a quick way to do it using `reduce`. It's super-effective when you need a way to convert an array into a primitive value.

Comment: Btw. you can accept only one answer (that helped you the most) and upvote/downvote as many as you like (useful/not useful).

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time using this forum and wow such good and fast replies.

I ended up using ChillNUT's code and the end result is this:

```
function IconCount() {
divs = document.querySelectorAll('#IconFX > div');
var divsArray = [].slice.call(divs);
var displayNone = divsArray.filter(function(el) { 
return getComputedStyle(el).display === "none"
});
var displayShow = divsArray.filter(function(el) { 
return getComputedStyle(el).display !== "none"
});
var numberOfHiddenDivs = displayNone.length;
var numberOfVisibleDivs = displayShow.length;
document.getElementById('VisibleIcons').innerHTML = numberOfVisibleDivs;
document.getElementById('HiddenIcons').innerHTML = numberOfHiddenDivs;
}
```

This way I can call this as a function when anything is hidden or visible and can interact with these output values with another script.