# how to store values of visible li elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a list of inputs and storing the values in an array when the add button is clicked.
All works well, but I have introduced the possibility to remove items in the list effectively by hiding the 'deleted' elements from the DOM.

Now I need to remove the hidden elements from the array.
To keep things simple, I thought to store in the array only the visible elements (instead of removing the hidden element from the array).
To do so I am looking at adapting the 'how to count visible elements' code in:  [(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634146/javascript-count-visible-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634146/javascript-count-visible-elements) but it doesn't work and a list of '[object HTMLLIElement]' is displayed when displaying the array on an alert.

This is my code:

```js
// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function () {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  };
}

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function addNumber() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("number").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === "") {
    alert("Add at least one phone number!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  // remove elements from form after added to list
  document.getElementById("number").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  // without this, the element is not deleted
  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function () {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    };
  }
}

// store values after submit
function submitRecords() {
  divs = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  var divsArray = [].slice.call(divs);
  var displayShow = divsArray.filter(function (el) {
    return getComputedStyle(el).display !== "none";
  });
  alert(displayShow);
}
```

```css
#myUL {
  /* text-align: center; */
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

/* Style the list items */
ul li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #eee;
  border-top: lightgrey 1px solid;
  border-bottom: lightgrey 1px solid;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  /* this allows for the borders of 2 adiacent items to overlap */
  margin-top: -1px;
}

/* Style the close button */
.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.addBtn {
  background: #eee;
  border: black 1px solid;
  padding: 4px;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

  .addBtn:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
```

```html
<div class="inputForm">
  <form>
    <input
      type="text"
      id="number"
      placeholder="Enter number"
      onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
    />
    <span onclick="addNumber()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
    <br /><br />
    <input
      onclick="submitRecords()"
      id="send"
      type="submit"
      value="SEND"
    />
  </form>
</div>

<!-- this is needed to generate the list of numbers -->
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add relevant HTML markup and make [mre] you can use`<>` button in editor to make a snippet...

Comment: @ikiK I have added the snippet for the elements of the form that concern the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a .value in function addNumber which seems to be spurious, on this line:

```
  divs = document.getElementsByTagName("li").value;
```

when this is removed the console.log shows li elements.

The code for adding onclick functionality to the span elements looks as though it is trying to step through a (non-existent?) array, and it is doing this each time a number is added. Removing this code and instead setting up the onclick as a span element is created seems to work.

Here is the altered code:

```
<!-- Added HTML for testing -->
<input id="number" value=999 onchange="addNumber();"/>
<button onclick="submitRecords();">submit records</button>
<ul id="myUL"></ul>

<script>
function submitRecords() {   
  var divs = (document.getElementsByTagName("li"));// REMOVED .value
  var divsArray = [].slice.call(divs);
  var displayShow = divsArray.filter(function (el) {
    return getComputedStyle(el).display !== "none";
  });
  var numbers=[];
      var keys = [];
  for (var i=0;i<displayShow.length;i++) {
    numbers[i]=displayShow[i].childNodes[0].textContent;
    console.log(numbers[i]);
  }
  
}

function addNumber() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("number").value;
    var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
    li.appendChild(t);
    if (inputValue === "") {
      alert("Add at least one phone number!");
    } else {
      document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
    }

    // close button
    var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
    var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
    span.className = "close";
    span.onclick = function () { //ADDED so that an li element's span child gets this onclick function as soon as it is created
        var div = this.parentElement;
        div.style.display = "none";
      };
    span.appendChild(txt);
    li.appendChild(span);
    
 /* REMOVED       // hide element
    for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
      close[i].onclick = function () {
        var div = this.parentElement;
        div.style.display = "none";
      };
*/


  }
</script>
```

Comment: @A Haworth, I tried your suggestion, but removing the .value will give me a list of '[object HTMLLIElement]'. Also, removing the 'hide element' code, will prevent the elements to be hidden. But yes, perhaps that it is unnecessary for the question.

Comment: @Marcello, yes, I thought that was what you wanted - you then go through the list of the LI  elements, finding those which don't have display 'none' . Let me know if that isn't what you wanted.

Comment: @A Haworth, I need the value of the items still visible in the DOM to be stored in an array.

Comment: @Marcello displayShow is an array of all the li elements that don't have display:none. You can get the value (the number the user has typed in) for item number i in displayShow it is displayShow[i].innerHTML I will try it out and edit my answer (if it works).

Comment: @Marcello I've edited my answer and the displayed numbers are now saved in an array called numbers. I had forgotten that the span element was also in the li element so have obtained the actual number by taking the first child of each li element, not the whole innerHTML.

Comment: @A Haworth, your solution still doesn't work. I got the following response: '[object Text],[object Text],[object Text]'

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. It's interesting as my console.log showed the numbers for me. I've altered my code so that the textContent rather than the object itself is stored in the array.

Comment: this now works, thanks. also note that 'var keys = [];' is redundant

Answer (score 1):

Your idea to get only visible items is just fine, and you can do it like this:

```
function submitRecords() { 

const displayShow = [];
//declare array

[...document.querySelectorAll('#myUL li:not([style="display: none;"])')].forEach(element => {
//get all li items and for each of them:

    displayShow.push(element.textContent.slice(0, -1))
//push its text Content into array, and also just remove last x (button) character

  });
  console.clear();
  console.log(displayShow);
}
```

Ps: `li` element does not have `.value`, you can red content with: `textContent`

Just remove `onsubmit` event from form, and add back `onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"` to input i made modifications just for demonstration:

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}

// Click on a close button to hide the current list item
var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
  close[i].onclick = function () {
    var div = this.parentElement;
    div.style.display = "none";
  };
}

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function addNumber() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("number").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === "") {
    alert("Add at least one phone number!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  // remove elements from form after added to list
  document.getElementById("number").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  // without this, the element is not deleted
  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function () {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    };
  }
}

// store values after submit

function submitRecords() {  
const displayShow = [];
[...document.querySelectorAll('#myUL li:not([style="display: none;"])')].forEach(element => {
    displayShow.push(element.textContent.slice(0, -1))
  });
  console.clear();
  console.log(displayShow);
}
```

```css
#myUL {
  /* text-align: center; */
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

/* Style the list items */
ul li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #eee;
  border-top: lightgrey 1px solid;
  border-bottom: lightgrey 1px solid;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  /* this allows for the borders of 2 adiacent items to overlap */
  margin-top: -1px;
}

/* Style the close button */
.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.addBtn {
  background: #eee;
  border: black 1px solid;
  padding: 4px;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

  .addBtn:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
```

```html
<div class="inputForm">
  <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
    <input
      type="text"
      id="number"
      placeholder="Enter number"
      
    />
    <span onclick="addNumber()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
    <br /><br />
    <input
      onclick="submitRecords()"
      id="send"
      type="submit"
      value="SEND"
    />
  </form>
</div>

<!-- this is needed to generate the list of numbers -->
<ul id="myUL"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made only small modification to your code to get the desired values from the `<li>` element.

```
function submitRecords() {
  divs = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
  
  var divsArray = [];

  var displayShow = Object.values(divs).filter(function (el) {
    return getComputedStyle(el).display !== "none";
  });

 displayShow.forEach(function(item){let ind=item.innerHTML.indexOf('<span'); 
 divsArray.push(item.innerHTML.substr(0,ind))});
 alert(divsArray);
}
```